# Sorting array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, double

I've array of doubles and I'm sorting it using `Arrays.sort` problem is that in the output array I've something like this(this is array output after reverse):

> 0.002385171991295645
>
> ...
>
> 9.914204103773398E-4
>
> ...
>
> 1.00139601969068E-4
>
> 9.975711760353395E-5

and so on, as we can see shortest number are at the top and longest are at the bottom. Numbers in given range e.g. E-4 are sorted good. I've even created a sample code to test this:

```
double l1 = 0.002385171991295645;
double l2 = 9.914204103773398E-4;
if(l1 > l2) {
    System.out.println("TRUE");
} else {
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

And it gives me "TRUE", how to sort this array?

Comment: I don't see a problem, the numbers are sorted from the biggest to the smalles

Comment: `9.914204103773398E-4` *is* smaller than `0.002385171991295645`.

Comment: 0.002385171991295645 > 9.914204103773398E-4 that's quite OK

Comment: @user you do realize what `E-4` means, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't know what's the meaning of that `E-4` at the end.

```
9.914204103773398E-4
```

Is actually

```
9.914204103773398 * 10^-4
```

Which is *smaller* than `0.002385171991295645`.

For more details, visit the JLS - [**3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

Answer (score 2):

You are getting confused by the scientific notation (also known as [standard form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)).

`9.914204103773398E-4` means `9.91... x 10^(-4)`, i.e. `0.0009914...`. So this value is indeed smaller than `0.0023..`.

Answer (score 2):

The "e" or "E" means "exponent," which denotes [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Here's a useful example from [the primitive data types tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) on Oracle.com:

```
double d1 = 123.4;
double d2 = 1.234e2;
```

Those are both the same number. The "e" means, basically, `10^x` (`10` raised to the power of `x`) where the number that follows is `x`. So in the above, `1.234 * 10^2`. `10^2` is `100`, so `1.234 * 100` is `1.234`.

So looking at one of your numbers, `9.914204103773398E-4`, that's `9.914204103773398 * 10^-4`. `10^-4` is `0.0001`, so `9.914204103773398 * 0.0001`, which is `0.0009914103773398`.